# Eclipse cant see terminal created project in package explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, terminal

After creating a new android project from the terminal using:

```
  android create project --target 2  
 --name newApp2 
 --path ./newApp2Project                 
 --activity newApp2Activity 
 --package com.android.newApp2
```

i discovered that this creates the project folder in the android-sdks/tools folder.  i moved the project folder to my workspace folder that my eclipse package explorer uses. I wanted to see if i could open my new project in eclipse but the package explorer does not list the new project.  I restarted the eclipse and still nothing... how can i see my project in my eclipse package explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android create project` does not create `.classpath` and `.project`, which eclipse depends on, and only with these two files(configurations properly set) will a folder be treated as an eclipse project.

All you can do is copying these files from some other existing eclipse projects, change the project name in `.classpath` to the name of your newly created project. Now you can import the project from eclipse by `File`->`Import`->`General`->`Existing Projects into workspace`. You may need to change `.project` accordingly, say you may want to remove some dependency libraries from `.project`, since it's a newly created project, it should not depend on any libraries. You can also manage libarary dependencies from eclipse by `Right clicking project name`->`Build Path`->`Configure Build Path`->`Libraries`.